# How to short two points(2 wires) without using relay

Tags: relay

I have made a circuit with ESP8266 which triggers a relay. Actually, I want to bypass a button which is on a 3rd electronic device, which is a closed box with a very complex circuit.

I have soldered out the connections of the switch from that device. By using relay I can short that, but a relay is bit bulky,

Is there any other way to achieve this? (The other device is a DC operated device)

Comment: There are small relays as well. Or you can use a properly connected optocoupler

Comment: You need to tell us what voltage is across the wires when open circuit and what current is drawn when the wires close. Also confirm that it is a DC signal.

Comment: Be sure to include as much information as possible or else we don't have much to work with. What is the device, and what is the role of the button? (Volume Up, Power, etc). What kind of physical button is it? (Tact switch, silicone pad, etc) Also tell us what size you're looking for (How big is your relay, and how small do you want it to be?)

Comment: Or you know, just ignore us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solid state relays are compact, don't have any moving parts (no wear and tear), cheaper, and will have a longer lifetime.
[image]

You can further search carefully for your application (voltage rating, current rating, package and other options) with the link below:

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/solid-state-relays/183

Comment: YEs, optocoupler is a good option i believe,

Comment: HI
 got some optocoupler, here is the data sheet: http://www.secosgmbh.com/datasheet/products/Photocoupler/DIP4/BL817.pdf

will this work in my case?

Comment: What is the function of the button? What will be Vorlage across the button? Only when the details of the requirement is clear, it helps to provide useful reply

Comment: it is a button inside intercom phone for building security door. voltage is +14 volts